# QlikView Data Load from Oracle Script

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, qlikview

I have a small problem with loading data from an Oracle database into QlikView 11 using the following script:

```
SET ThousandSep='.';
SET DecimalSep=',';
SET MoneyThousandSep='.';
SET MoneyDecimalSep=',';
SET MoneyFormat='#.##0,00 €;-#.##0,00 €';
SET TimeFormat='hh:mm:ss';
SET DateFormat='DD.MM.YYYY';
SET TimestampFormat='DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss[.fff]';
SET MonthNames='Jan;Feb;Mrz;Apr;Mai;Jun;Jul;Aug;Sep;Okt;Nov;Dez';
SET DayNames='Mo;Di;Mi;Do;Fr;Sa;So';

ODBC CONNECT TO [Oracle X;DBQ=db1.dc.man.lan] (XUserId is X, XPassword is Y);

SQL SELECT *
FROM UC140017."TABLE_1";

SQL SELECT *
FROM UC140017."TABLE_2";

SQL SELECT *
FROM UC140017."TABLE_3";

SQL SELECT *
FROM UC140017."TABLE_4";

SQL SELECT *
FROM UC140017."TABLE_5";
```

This results in the following output:

```
Connecting to Oracle X;DBQ=db1.dc.man.lan
Connected
TABLE_1 2.421 lines fetched
TABLE_2 1 lines fetched
TABLE_2 << TABLE_3 2 lines fetched
TABLE_2 << TABLE_4 22 lines fetched
TABLE_2 << TABLE_5 22 lines fetched
```

There is no reason why TABLE_3, TABLE_4 & TABLE_5 are joined to TABLE_2. This relationship doesn't exist in the database and I don't see the option to change this in QlikView. Does anyone of you know where this is coming from and has suggestions how to fix this? Thanks!

Best,
Christoph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the columns in Table_2,Table_3,Table_4 and Table_5 are the same number and same names then QV will auto concatenate them in one table. To avoid this you can use "NoConcatenate" prefix:

```
SQL SELECT *
FROM UC140017."TABLE_1";

NoConcatenate
SQL SELECT *
FROM UC140017."TABLE_2";

NoConcatenate    
SQL SELECT *
FROM UC140017."TABLE_3";

NoConcatenate    
SQL SELECT *
FROM UC140017."TABLE_4";

NoConcatenate
SQL SELECT *
FROM UC140017."TABLE_5";
```

This will force QV to treat all tables as different tables. Be aware that, if this is the case, then after the reload you will have massive synthetic key.

Comment: You could also use the qualify statement to avoid the syn key

Comment: Of course. I just assumed (dont know why) that the tables will be stored in qvds after this.

Comment: Thanks guys! Both solutions seem to work. In the end I went for the QUALIFY solution.